# Android Equivalent to NSURLProtocol in iOS

Tags: android, ios

I am using NSURLHttpProtocol in iOS to intercept the network calls and get information in regards to which url is processed, when request initiated or complete and so on. I want to know how to intercept the network calls in android too. I have tried using WebViewClient but it just tells me about that webView .

I want to know if a particular call is made through webview, which urls are processed, which images are loaded in android.

Please suggest some solution on how to proceed with this.

Example: 
If I have a android based cordova application which basically has some set of webviews. How can I intercept those network calls, which are made through the resources inside the webview ?

Comment: A Google search on `NSURLHttpProtocol` is not coming up with anything much. Are you sure you that is correct?

Comment: @CommonsWare : Correcting `NSUrlHttpProtocol` with `NSUrlProtocol`

Comment: @CommonsWare : The question was asked in 2012. That time android volley was not present. The question is totally different.

Comment: "The question was asked in 2012" -- correct. It is still a duplicate question. Moreover, the answer given then is still correct. "That time android volley was not present" -- Volley has nothing to do with intercepting network calls made by a `WebView`, as I have noted on the existing answer. "The question is totally different" -- please explain, **completely and precisely**, how your question is different, considering that the two questions have similar titles and identical lines of inquiry (what the Android equivalent of `NSUrlProtocol` is, if any).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several third party libraries that does that for you:

- [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)
- [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)
- [AsyncHttp](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)
- [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

The most used ones are Retrofit and Volley, you can read a good comparison about them in [this article](http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/)

Comment: Does any of this, intercept the network calls if present in hybrid-android app too. ?

Comment: I actually never tried, but seems like Cordova already [uses OkHttp](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/tree/3.5.x/framework/src/com/squareup/okhttp)

Comment: None of these have anything to do with intercepting network requests made by a `WebView`.

Comment: I skipped reading the "calls through webview" part of the question by accident. You're right, I'll delete my answer

Comment: I wish I can delete it .. It's marked as an answer now